# VBA Getting a function to return a string

Tags: vba

I have a column of values for universities. For example, I have a column with string "University of Michigan" and "UMich"

why won't the following function return back in the cell a string "University of Michigan"

```
Function CleanUniCode(entry) As Variant
If entry = "UMich" Then entry = "University of Michigan"

End Function
```

Also tried this and the cell is returning 0, not sure why.

```
Function CleanUniCode(entry) As Variant
If entry Like "[UMich]" Then
entry = "University of Michigan"
ElseIf entry Like "[UPenn]" Then
entry = "University of Pennsylvania"
Else:
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you assigned the return value to `entry`, but you should assign it to `CleanUniCode`:

```
Function CleanUniCode(entry) As Variant
    If entry = "UMich" Then CleanUniCode = "University of Michigan"
End Function
```

Always assign the return value to the function name.

Comment: Question: Why doesn't the following work? It gives me a value error in return, If entry = "UMich" or "Umich" Then CleanUniCode = "University of Michigan"

Comment: Because you must have `entry = ...` for each piece of the OR statement: `If entry = "UMich" or entry = "Umich" Then CleanUniCode = "University of Michigan"`

Comment: how could I code so that if the function encounters another school, say "Harvard", the function just passes it over and leaves it as is

Comment: In that case, change the `CleanUniCode = "University of Michigan"` back to `entry = "University of Michigan"` and then before `End Function` add the line: `CleanUniCode = entry`